# Why does list.remove() not work in this for-loop?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists :

```
W = [[5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

From each list in `W`, I want to remove the zero entries.

I have tried the following :

```
for idx in range(len(W)):
    W[idx].remove(0)
print(W)
```

But it will always return

```
[[5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Nothing has changed here. I am aware of the fact that I cannot change an object while I am iterating over it, however as I am not iterating over `W` but over `len(W)`, I don't see why my code wouldn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Better way would be to use a list comprehension and overwrite `W`.

Comment: If find that your code does reduce the size of each sub list since they all have at least one `0` in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As avloss said, that remove only removes the first occurrence. Do a list comprehension.

```
for idx in range(len(W)):
    W[idx] = [i for i in W[idx] if i != 0]
print(W)
```

and as @meowgoesthedog suggested, you could do an overall list comprehension:

```
W = [lst[item for item in lst if item !=0] for lst in W]
```

Comment: If you are going to use comprehensions for the inner lists, might as well use one for the outer list as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove all `0` elements you can user list comprehension and filter:

```py
W = [[5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
for idx in range(len(W)):
    W[idx] = [i for i in W[idx] if i != 0]
print(W)
```

output looks like this:

```
[[5.0], [5.0], [], [5.0], [5.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension and filter function to delete the items having zero value in every sublist of `W` :

```
W = [[5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
nw = [list(filter(lambda a: a != 0, k)) for k in W]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[[5.0], [5.0], [], [5.0], [5.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's better to use filter with a lambda expression in order to filter out the zero values.

```
    for idx in range(len(W)):
        W[idx]=list((filter(lambda a: a != 0, W[idx])))
        print(W)
```

This will give you the next output:

```
    [[5.0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
    [[5.0], [5.0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
    [[5.0], [5.0], [], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
    [[5.0], [5.0], [], [5.0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
    [[5.0], [5.0], [], [5.0], [5.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension should be enough.

```
W = [[5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
li  = [ [j] for i in W for j in i if j!=0]
print(li)
#[[5.0], [5.0], [5.0], [5.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are more than 1 zeros in each sublist, we have to use two `for` loops, if you want to stick with a loop based solution.

```
In [75]: for lst in W:
    ...:     num_zeros = lst.count(0)
    ...:     for _ in range(num_zeros):
    ...:         lst.remove(0)


In [76]: W
Out[76]: [[5.0], [5.0], [], [5.0], [5.0]]
```

---

Now, your code:

```
In [79]: for idx in range(len(W)):
    ...:     W[idx].remove(0)
    ...: print(W)
```

yields the solution:

```
[[5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0]]
```

which we can see is short of 1 zeros from the counts of zeros in the input list. This is because `remove(obj)` will remove only the first occurrence of the object.

Answer (score -2):

This is because `l.remove(0)` means **remove first occurrence of that element**. to remove element by index you can use `del`

```py
W = [[5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0], [5.0, 0, 0, 0]]
for idx in range(len(W)):
    del W[idx][0]
print(W)
```

this produces

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```